# Certificate Chain Error with Custom CA in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl-certificate

Ran into an issue earlier today with errors on our internal certificate. Other users/consumers/clients were not getting the errors. Was getting an error "there are issues with the sites certificate chain" and then when viewing the certificate, sure enough just the end certificate was listed, not the whole chain tree. The cert used to work fine after I generated it and installed on our servers a month or so ago and continues to work for my colleagues.

I am on Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue on a whim by going to my custom CA settings here chrome://settings/certificates?search=cert and then Authorities and "edit"ing my CA, unchecking all the boxes, pressing okay, then re-editing and re-checking them and pressing okay, no browser restart needed. Next page refresh and my Certificate error was gone!

So this is likely a Chrome bug of some sort and its interaction with NSSDB.

[image]